# Azure + react js pdf + Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, azure, pdf

I have an asp.net core 2.0 solution using react.js as a frontend. I published my app to Azure (PaaS) some time ago. Everything was ok till I tried to generate pdf.

On my local machine it works, but on the Azure App Service I got the following exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException","Message":"Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms

I tried to set already the 
`"engines":{"node":version}` or 
`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` (on azure variables)

frontend code:

```
private generatePdf() {

    let htmlContent = document.getElementById("dataToPrint");

    GetDetailsPdf(this.props.prop1, htmlContent.innerHTML).then((data: Blob) => {
        // Create of hidden anchor for start download in browser
        var a: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a");
        a.hidden = true;
        document.body.appendChild(a);

        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = `${this.props.prop1}_${this.props.prop2}.pdf`;
        a.click();

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
}
```

backend:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportPdf(
        Guid id, 
        [FromBody] JObject jObject, 
        [FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices,
        [FromServices] IHtmlToPdfConverter converter)
{
    var htmlJObject = jObject.First;
    var htmlContent = htmlJObject.First.Value<string>();

    var pdfFile = await converter.GetPdfFile(htmlContent);

    return File(pdfFile, "application/pdf", $"MyPDf_{id}.pdf");
}
```

where converter just calls

```
nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("./pdf", htmlTemplate);
```

Comment: Please also show the node.js code and tell us where you put it.

Comment: Have you [enabled the `NodeServices`](http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/08/24/javascriptservices-asp-net-core/) inside the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class?